# How to get selenium to count how many classes there are containing class name?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I have html that I am trying to scrape and I want selenium to loop through x amount of times because there are x html classes that contain `heat-yyyy` in them.

I would use the code
`class_count_text = _______.text class_count = len(class_count_text)`

and then tell Python to loop through `class_count` times.
Should I be using `driver.find_element(By.Xpath) or By.Class_Name`?

Comment: You can use find_element**s** so that you would obtain elements containing the classes and you would be able to iterate over that collection.

Comment: That would work but unfortunately they ascend in name. They are surfing heats (rounds) so the first one is heat-0001, second is heat-0002, etc

Answer (score 0):

class_count = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@class,"heat-")]')